# Handling HTML Form Array with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out how to handle this:
I'm trying to create two arrays, where I enter 4 quizzes for a class, and then loop through them in my PHP code.

```
<tr>
<td>ENGL110</td>
<td><input type="text" name="EnglArray[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="EnglArray[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="EnglArray[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="EnglArray[]"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>MATH242</td>
<td><input type="text" name="MathArray[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="MathArray[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="MathArray[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="MathArray[]"></td>
</tr>
```

This is how I'm trying to retrieve it in my PHP code

```
$EnglArray = $_POST["EnglArray"];

$MathArray = $_POST["MathArray"];

print_r($EnglArray);
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but it seems like my array is always empty, and `print_r` doesn't output anything.

Comment: Try first doing print_r($_POST) to see what you're getting overall.

Comment: What is the method of your form?  Are you using POST or GET?

Comment: did you use <form> tag in the beginning of your code?

Comment: the <form> tag definitely works, and I'm using POST

Comment: so print_r($_POST) returns:
Array ( [Engl1] => 90 [Engl2] => 39 [Engl3] => 34 [Engl4] => 25 [Math1] => 34 [Math2] => 34 [Math3] => 53 [Math4] => 93 [Cisc1] => 34 [Cisc2] => 93 [Cisc3] => 43 [Cisc4] => 95 )
**I also have a Cisc array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
<?php
  foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
   if (!is_array($value)){
     echo "$key = $value<br />";
   } else {
     echo "$key is an array:<br />";
     foreach ($value as $valKey=>$valVal){
      echo "$valKey = $valVal<br />";
     }

   }
  }
?>
```